# Network connectivity to the Fullnodes

Tags: bitcoin-core

What would the router configuration (port forwarding) be if I have two nodes 192.168.2.21 and 192.168.2.22 running bitcoin and wants to enable port forwarding for them both on 8333?

Answer (score -1):

Just open **TCP** incoming/outcoming connection for 192.168.2.21 & 192.168.2.22 for port 8333 in you router configuration page.